# Dropdown Custom Field - Is this possible

Tags: custom-fields

We would like to have the ability to use a dropdown as one of the custom fields linked to an activity. This would enable us to search on this field without mis-spelling causing problems on the future. Is this possible as I can't see an option for a dropdown when setting up a new custom field?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this by using "select" option

Please try to use text - with select option (Data and Input Field Type) and fill up the details below or you can select an existing set from the drop down

If you are not sure about the option please let me know I can post some Example with screen shots

I guess this helps !!!

Comment: Great - that is just what I was after. Thanks for the help.